# Cannot view TextMeshPro (TMP) text in scene view or game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

As you can see, I am unable to view any sort of text inside the TMP. It was working perfectly fine until yesterday. Also, all my Layers are visible in the settings. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: img]

Comment: You have no font asset assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you have no font asset assigned. Without a font asset assigned there are no glyphs for the component to reference when rendering your message.

[image: This]

Either drag and drop a `TMP_Font` asset from your editor, or click on the little target symbol which will bring up an editor window of all types `TMP_Font`, then assign one of the fonts that pop up. If you are still having issues after assigning a font let me know.

Comment: @JayNewbie Mistakes like this happen all the time - no worries. Usually, just need another pair of eyes to look at the issue. If this post answered your question, you can close the question by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the post. It closes the question and lets others know there is a working answer to your question.

Comment: Why in the world would Unity not include a default font?

Answer (score 0):

- I clicked Gizmos to show yellow rect area.
- I expanded it enough to cover the text.
- And fixed.

[Yellow rect area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lewqY.png)